# Put text in center/middle in header

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to put the text `ONLINE NEWS SERVICE` vertically and horizontally `center` aligned and exactly in the middle of header

But if I add `<span align="center" style="text-align:center;align-content:center; vertical-align:middle;">ONLINE NEWS SERVICE</span>` with all possible middle and center settings, the text does not appear in middle and centrally aligned horizontally and vertically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this once

```css
span.title{
  display:block;
margin:0px auto !important;
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
 <!-- To display online news text -->
 <span class="title">ONLINE NEWS SERVICE</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

Text usually doesn't align as expected either because it is the child element of a container which doesn't cover as much width as you think it does ( so maybe you should check the width of :

```
<header id="masthead">
```

), or the element containing the text isn't being styled as a block-level element with the width covering the entire area you want the text to be centralized within; So you could also try:

```
header#masthead span {
display:block;
width:100%;
text-align:center
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First you should need to set the width for your middle span. This is how your css will look.

```
element.style {
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  width: 50%;
}
```